# Is it appropriate to call professor?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I exchanged an email with a professor on Thursday and he asked me if I am available to call him on a specific time next Monday. I replied the email to confirm the time but no reply from him. Therefore, I resent the email on Friday to re- confirm that he knows that I will make the call. However, no reply as well. So I am wondering if it is appropriate for me to call him at the time he indicated next Monday even without his reply?

Answer (score 12):

Sure. You have booked a time, make the call. If you want to be sure, ask him over the phone if it is still a good time.

Academics are busy and slow responders, so since you confirmed your emails may have been given the lowest priority.

Comment: So I just call him as scheduled on Monday and ask him then if it is still a good time to talk, right?

Answer (score 2):

When he has asked you to call him by phone; call him in the office hours to the provided phone number.

May be he knew he won't have access to his email on the following days and he asked you to have a telephone conversation instead. That may be why he is not responding your email too.